# Overriding FastAPI dependencies that have parameters

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pytest, fastapi

I'm trying to test my FastAPI endpoints by overriding the injected database using the officially recommended method in the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/).

The function I'm injecting the db with is a closure that allows me to build any desired database from a MongoClient by giving it the database name whilst (I assume) still working with FastAPI depends as it returns a closure function's signature. No error is thrown so I think this method is correct:

```python
# app
def build_db(name: str):
    def close():
          return build_singleton_whatever(MongoClient, args....)
     return close
```

Adding it to the endpoint:

```python
# endpoint
@app.post("/notification/feed")
async def route_receive_notifications(db: Database = Depends(build_db("someDB"))):
   ...
```

And finally, attempting to override it in the tests:

```python
# pytest
# test_endpoint.py
fastapi_app.dependency_overrides[app.build_db] = lambda x: lambda: x
```

However, the dependency doesn't seem to override at all and the test ends up creating a MongoClient with the IP of the production database as in normal execution.

**So**, any ideas on overriding FastAPI dependencies that are given parameters in their endpoints?

I have tried creating a mock closure function with no success:

```python
def mock_closure(*args):
    def close():
        return args
    return close

app.dependency_overrides[app.build_db] = mock_closure('otherDB')
```

And I have also tried providing the same signature, including the parameter, with still no success:

```python
app.dependency_overrides[app.build_db('someDB')] = mock_closure('otherDB')
```

*Edit note* I'm also aware I can create a separate function that creates my desired database and use that as the dependency, but I would much prefer to use this dynamic version as it's more scalable to using more databases in my apps and avoids me writing essentially repeated functions just so they can be cleanly injected.

Comment: Initial guess would be to either move the inner function out from function to be a separate function (which then would have a unique reference you can register in your overrides), or try to resolve it by having it returned: `app.dependency_overrides[app.build_db("dummy")]`; since what is _actually_ registered in the dependency hierarchy is the inner function (which is why registering the override for `app.build_db` doesn't work - as that just returns the inner function when the dependency gets resolved). I'm unsure if Python would return the same function in that case (I'd guess no).

Comment: @MatsLindh I had a go at this because the logic makes sense but it didn't seem to have any effect either. I think it's definitely some sort of problem with the mapping as it doesn't affect the endpoint's dependency at all, which means the app dependency overriding isn't doing anything in this specific case. Find it weird the docs don't talk about this scenario, so maybe it's just not supported.

Comment: @JoeMoon did you find a solution to this question? I have a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796168/fastapi-pytest-how-to-override-a-fastapi-dependency-that-accepts-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My case involved an HTTP client wrapper, instead of a DB. I think it could be applied to your case as well.

Context: I want to inject values for a FastAPI handler's dependency to test various scenarios.

We have a handler with its dependencies

```py
@router.get("/{foo}")
async def get(foo, client = Depends(get_client)): # get_client is the key to override
  client = get_client()
  return await client.request(foo)
```

The function `get_client` is the dependency I want to override in my tests. It returns a `Client` object that takes a function that performs an HTTP request to an external service (this function actually wraps `aiohttp`, but that's not the important part). Here's its barebone definition:

```py
class Client:
  def __init__(request):
    self._request = request
  
  async def request(self, params):
    return await self._request(params)
```

We want to test various responses from the external service, so we need to build the function that returns a function that returns a `Client` object (sorry for the tongue-twister), with its params:

```py
def get_client_getter(response):
  async def request_mock(*args, **kwargs):
    return response

  def get_client():
    return Client(request=request_mock)

  return get_client()
```

Then in the various tests we have:

```py
def test_1():
    app.dependency_overrides[get_client] = get_client_getter(1)
    ...

def test_true():
    app.dependency_overrides[get_client] = get_client_getter(True)
    ...

def test_none():
    app.dependency_overrides[get_client] = get_client_getter(None)
    ...
```

Comment: I am going the same approach but it is not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796168/fastapi-pytest-how-to-override-a-fastapi-dependency-that-accepts-arguments

Answer (score 1):

I use next fixtures for main db overriding to db for testing:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine

from settings import get_settings


@pytest.fixture()
async def get_engine():
    engine = create_async_engine(get_settings().test_db_url)
    yield engine
    await engine.dispose()


@pytest.fixture()
async def db_session(get_engine) -> AsyncSession:
    async with get_engine.begin() as connection:
        async with async_session(bind=connection) as session:
            yield session
            await session.close()


@pytest.fixture()
def override_get_async_session(db_session: AsyncSession) -> Callable:
    async def _override_get_async_session():
        yield db_session

    return _override_get_async_session
```

Comment: I like this suggestion but going to wait for an answer that might match my strategy more closely. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your implementation getting in your way:

1. As you are *calling* `build_db` right in the `route_receive_notifications` function definition, the latter receives nested `close` function as a dependency. And it's impossible to override it. To fix this you would need to avoid calling your dependency right away and still provide it with db name. For that you can either define a new dependency to inject name into `build_db`:

```
# app
def get_db_name():
    return "someDB"

def build_db(name: str = Depends(get_db_name)):
    ...

# endpoint
@app.post("/notification/feed")
async def route_receive_notifications(db: Database = Depends(build_db)):
   ...
```

or use `functools.partial` (shorter but less elegant):

```
# endpoint
from functools import partial

@app.post("/notification/feed")
async def route_receive_notifications(db: Database = Depends(partial(build_db, "someDB"))):
   ...
```

2. FastAPI requires dependency overriding function to have [the same signature as the original dependency](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/c5be1b0550f17d827721a5be1dc4344e73b1993f/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L279). Simply switching from `*args` to a single parameter is enough, although using the same argument name and type makes it easier to support in future. Of course you need to provide the function itself as a value for `dependency_overrides` *without calling it*:

```
def mock_closure(name: str):
    def close():
        return name
    return close

app.dependency_overrides[app.build_db] = mock_closure
```