# fastapi pytest: how to override a fastapi dependency that accepts arguments?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, pytest, fastapi

I have this small [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) FastAPI application which works fine as expected:

```
# run.py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


###########

def dep_with_arg(inp):
    def sub_dep():
        return inp
    return sub_dep


@app.get("/a")
def a(v: str = Depends(dep_with_arg("a"))):
    return v


###########


def dep_without_arg():
    return "b"


@app.get("/b")
def b(v: str = Depends(dep_without_arg)):
    return v


###########


def main():
    uvicorn.run(
        "run:app",
        host="0.0.0.0",
        reload=True,
        port=8000,
        workers=1
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

notice the difference between the dependencies of the `/a` and `/b` endpoints. in the `/a` endpoint, I have created a dependency that accepts an argument. both endpoints are working as expected when I call them.

I now try to test the endpoints while overriding the dependencies as below:

```
from run import app, dep_without_arg, dep_with_arg
from starlette.testclient import TestClient


def test_b():
    def dep_override_for_dep_without_arg():
        return "bbb"

    test_client = TestClient(app=app)
    test_client.app.dependency_overrides[dep_without_arg] = dep_override_for_dep_without_arg
    resp = test_client.get("/b")
    resp_json = resp.json()
    assert resp_json == "bbb"


###########


def test_a_method_1():
    def dep_override_for_dep_with_arg(inp):
        def sub_dep():
            return "aaa"

        return sub_dep

    test_client = TestClient(app=app)
    test_client.app.dependency_overrides[dep_with_arg] = dep_override_for_dep_with_arg
    resp = test_client.get(
        "/a",
    )
    resp_json = resp.json()
    assert resp_json == "aaa"


def test_a_method_2():
    def dep_override_for_dep_with_arg(inp):
        return "aaa"

    test_client = TestClient(app=app)
    test_client.app.dependency_overrides[dep_with_arg] = dep_override_for_dep_with_arg
    resp = test_client.get(
        "/a",
    )
    resp_json = resp.json()
    assert resp_json == "aaa"


def test_a_method_3():
    def dep_override_for_dep_with_arg(inp):
        return "aaa"

    test_client = TestClient(app=app)
    test_client.app.dependency_overrides[dep_with_arg] = dep_override_for_dep_with_arg("aaa")
    resp = test_client.get(
        "/a",
    )
    resp_json = resp.json()
    assert resp_json == "aaa"


def test_a_method_4():
    def dep_override_for_dep_with_arg():
        return "aaa"

    test_client = TestClient(app=app)
    test_client.app.dependency_overrides[dep_with_arg] = dep_override_for_dep_with_arg
    resp = test_client.get(
        "/a",
    )
    resp_json = resp.json()
    assert resp_json == "aaa"
```

`test_b` passes as expected but all the other tests fail:

```
FAILED test.py::test_a_method_1 - AssertionError: assert 'a' == 'aaa'
FAILED test.py::test_a_method_2 - AssertionError: assert 'a' == 'aaa'
FAILED test.py::test_a_method_3 - AssertionError: assert 'a' == 'aaa'
FAILED test.py::test_a_method_4 - AssertionError: assert 'a' == 'aaa'
```

How should I override `dep_with_arg` in the example above?

---

related question: [Overriding FastAPI dependencies that have parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74689457/overriding-fastapi-dependencies-that-have-parameters)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the dependency function in a lru cache decorator (`functools.lru_cache`) ? Since you'll get a new function each time now, there is no match between what is being overridden and what you're trying to override - but if the same function gets returned every time for the same parameter, it might work as expected

Comment: As I suggested on one of your other posts, why don't you just create the dependency function globally, and then use them? So `dep_a = dep_with_arg("a")` etc, and then using them like `Depends(dep_a)` etc? Then you can easily override: `app.dependency_overrides[dep_a] = dep_override_for_dep_with_arg`.

Comment: @M.O. your solution is working and I am going to use it. I don't even need to define it globally. I just import them and they work

Comment: @M.O. But still I see it as a limitation. If I want to dynamically define dependencies and generate many of these dependencies on the fly, then it is a limitation.

Comment: In that case, see if the solution  @MatsLindh proposes works (decorating your dependency function with `@functools.lru_cache`). That should mean that calling `dep_with_arg("a")` twice returns the exact same object. Ib your test, you'd then do ` test_client.app.dependency_overrides[dep_with_arg("a")] = dep_override_for_dep_with_arg`.

Comment: You can also make a helper function that keeps a dictionary of all the resolved functions, and then return those - but that means that you've really just implemented your own cache in the same way as lru_cache does for you (except for the lru part).

Comment: @M.O. I think you have not understood my concern. I am saying suppose I want to create dep_with_arg("a"), dep_with_arg("b"), ...., dep_with_arg("x"), dep_with_arg("xyza"), dep_with_arg("an-arbitrary-name").

caching will not help me here. caching is helpful if I want to create any of them like dep_with_arg("a") more than once

Comment: @AminBa I understand what you want. The issue here is that `dep_with_arg` is **not** used as a dependency, its return value is. Therefore, you can't use it in `dependency_overrides`, because that simply maps one function to another.

Comment: That's why caching helps, it makes `dep_with_arg` return the same object when called with the same argument, so that `dependency_overrides` can map it correctly.

Comment: I understand you want to override all usages of `dep_with_arg` at once,  and I'm not sure that's possible. You might be able to do something clever by [subclassing `defaultdict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912455/11612918) and replacing `dependency_overrides`, but you'll have to investigate that.

Comment: You might also be able to get it working by refactoring everything inside `sub_dep` to a separate function, and then patching that with `unittest.mock.patch`.

Comment: @M.O. but I am not using the build fastapi's dependency override functionality which is a powerful tool and better tha monkey patching